# Is it possible to customize formatting of JS toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, internationalization

How wonderful that javascript has a native i18n API without the need for any external dependencies!

But is there any way to customize its output in anyway? or build a custom localization that can be consistent? I've found the documentation to be fairly confusing in this area. There are two issues I keep running into trying to use the native functions:

#### Inconsistent behaviour across browsers

```
(-5).toLocaleString('fr-ca', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD'})
// IE11: "(5,00 $)"
// Chrome: "-5,00 $"
// requirements: "−5,00 $"
```

#### No way to specify specific formatting

Our accessibility testers require negative currency values to be printed like this:

```
(-5).toLocaleString('en-ca', {style: 'currency', currency: 'CAD'})
// requirements: "$−5.00"
// (Using unicode char U+2212 (minus sign) and flipping minus and $.
// Most browsers: "-$5.00"
```

I've read some things about specifying which locale to use, but not a lot about how to customize one the way you can in Moment.js and similar libraries. I really like the idea of using a built-in API, but if it can't help us meet business requirements it may not be worth it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Number.prototype.toLocale = function() {
  return (`$` + Math.round(this, 2)).replace(".", ",");
}
```

Comment: If going down that route and overriding functions, it would be better to not even use the native functions, since that doesn't account for different currency types, thousands separators, decimal length specification etc.

Comment: Yes, seems the only way since the native api is not reliable

Comment: I'm currently looking for a way that still takes advantage of the built-in API functionality, but I'm beginning to think that using a separate library will be better in the long run.